# Implement a Moore State Machine

Tags: code-golf

This challenge is a slightly different kind of Code Golf challenge. Rather than coding to match IO, you code to match an interface.

#### Background

[Finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) are very useful design models for modeling event-based programming. A state machine is defined by a set of states and tranitions between them. The machine can be in one and only one state at any given time: the *current state*. Naturally, the machine has an *initial state*. When an event occurs, it may change it's state to another state; this is called a *transition*. A [Moore machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) is simply a FSM which can produce output; each state can produce an output.

For example, consider the following state machine which models a turnstile:

[image: Image of a turnstile]
[image: Basic state machine example]

The `Locked` state is the initial state of the machine. Whenever the turnstile is `Push`ed from this state, we do nothing (go back to the `Locked` state). However, if we receive a `Coin`, we transition to the `Un-locked` state. Extra `Coin`s do nothing, but a `Push` puts us back into the `Locked` state. It's not explicitly stated, but this FSM does have output: the `Locked` state has an output that tells the turnstile to lock it's arms, wheras the `Un-locked` state has an output that allows the turnstile to turn.

#### Task

You must implement a state machine class. This means that only languages with objects can compete. If there is an accepted alternative to objects in your language, that is valid (e.g. C can use structs with member functions). You must be able to access the functions of the object via `obj.function` or `obj->function` or whatever the accessor character for your language is. You are allowed to use a state machine library if it exists for your language, but you aren't allowed to use a class from the library "as your own" (don't just point at a premade class and say that that's your solution).

You must implement the following methods with exactly the specified names and signatures. However, you may capitalize the first letter or switch to `snake_case` (e.g. `mapOutput`, `MapOutput`, or `map_output` are all valid). Additionally, you may take an explicit *this* parameter as the first parameter:

- `map(State from, Event event, State to)` Defines a transition from `from` to `to` on the event `event`. If `from` and `event` have both been previously passed to this method before, you may do anything at all.
- `mapOutput(State state, Output output)` Assigns the given output to the given state. If `state` has been previously passed to this method before, you may do anything at all.
- `processEvent(Event event)` Advances the state machine according to the transitions defined via `map`. Basically, if the current state of the state machine is `from`, then `event` sets the current state to the state defined by a previously called `map(from, event, to)`. Throws an exception or fails violently if there is no mapping for the current state and given event.
- `getOutput()` Gets the output for the current state, as defined via `mapOutput`. Returns `null` or equivalent if there is no output defined for the given state. This may be an `Optional` type or similar if your language has one.
- Some sort of initial-state setting. This may be done in the constructor for your class, you may require `State` to have a default constructor, or you may provide some other way of setting the initial state.

The idea of `State`, `Event`, and `Output` is that they are generic types. You don't have to support generics per se, but this means that the user of your state machine will only pass in the type `State` for states, the type `Event` for events, and the type `Output` for outputs. However, the state machine is expected to be "generic" in that it should be possible to use any type as a `State`, any type as an `Event`, and any type as an `Output`.

Additionally, you map implement the `map` and `mapOutput` methods in a separate builder class, but I don't foresee that saving any bytes.

### Test cases

<sup>Note: don't trust my code. It's untested. It's intended mostly to give an idea of what you state machine will be used like</sup>

Java, classname `StateMachine`, initial-state passed via constructor:

```java
// States are ints, Events are chars, Outputs are ints
StateMachine machine = new StateMachine(0);
machine.map(0, '0', 1);
machine.map(0, '1', 2);
machine.map(0, '2', 3);
machine.map(1, '3', 0);
machine.map(1, '4', 2);
machine.map(2, '5', 0);
machine.map(2, '6', 1);
machine.map(2, '7', 2);
machine.mapOutput(1, 1);
machine.mapOutput(2, 10);
machine.mapOutput(3, 0);

// At this point, there should be absolutely no errors at all.
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `null`
machine.processEvent('0'); // Don't count on reference equality here...
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `1`
machine.processEvent('4');
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `10`
machine.processEvent('7');
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `10`
machine.processEvent('6');
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `1`
machine.processEvent('3');
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `null`
machine.processEvent('1');
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `10`
machine.processEvent('5');
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `null`
machine.processEvent('2');
System.out.println(machine.getOutput()); // Should output `0`
// Now any calls to processEvent should cause an exception to be thrown.
machine.processEvent('0'); // Throws an exception or crashes the program.
```

Ruby, classname `SM`, initial-state through `attr_writer` on `i`:

```ruby
sm = SM.new
sm.i = :init # All states will be symbols in this case.
[
  [:init, [], :init],
  [:init, [1], :state1],
  [:init, [2, 3], :state2],
  [:state1, [], :init],
  [:state1, [1], :state1],
  [:state1, [2, 3], :state2],
  [:state2, [], :init],
  [:state2, [1], :state1],
  [:state2, [2, 3], :state2]
].each { |from, trigger, to| sm.map(from, trigger, to) }
sm.mapOutput(:state1, [1])
sm.mapOutput(:state2, [[2, 3], 4, 5])

p sm.getOutput # => nil
sm.processEvent []
p sm.getOutput # => nil
sm.processEvent [1]
p sm.getOutput # => [1]
sm.processEvent [1]
p sm.getOutput # => [1]
sm.processEvent [2, 3]
p sm.getOutput # => [[2, 3], 4, 5]
sm.processEvent [2, 3]
p sm.getOutput # => [[2, 3], 4, 5]
sm.processEvent []
p sm.getOutput # => nil
sm.processEvent [2, 3]
p sm.getOutput # => [[2, 3], 4, 5]
sm.processEvent [1]
p sm.getOutput # => [1]
sm.processEvent []
p sm.getOutput # => nil
```

Note that even though there are only a few test cases, you must support arbitrary input to these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>132 125 121</s> 109

```js
M=c=>(s={},r={},{map:(f,e,t)=>s[f+e]=t,mapOutput:(s,o)=>r[s]=o,processEvent:e=>c=s[c+e],getOutput:x=>r[c]})
```

*Thanks to [edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65) for his suggestion of avoiding the full-fledged constructor approach!*

Here's a test snippet that works in Chrome and Firefox:

```js
M=c=>(s={},r={},{map:(f,e,t)=>s[f+e]=t,mapOutput:(s,o)=>r[s]=o,processEvent:e=>c=s[c+e],getOutput:x=>r[c]})

var sm = M('Locked');

var output = '';
var print = t => { output += t + "\n"; }

print(sm.getOutput() || 'not defined (there are no outputs currently defined)'); 

sm.map('Locked', 'Coin', 'Unlocked');
sm.map('Unlocked', 'Coin', 'Unlocked');
sm.map('Unlocked', 'Push', 'Locked');
sm.map('Locked', 'Push', 'Locked');

sm.mapOutput('Locked', 'Insert coin!');
sm.mapOutput('Unlocked', 'You can pass now.');

function event(name){
  print(' >> ' + name);
  sm.processEvent(name);
}

print(sm.getOutput());
event('Push');
print(sm.getOutput());
event('Coin');
print(sm.getOutput());
event('Coin');
print(sm.getOutput());
event('Push');
print(sm.getOutput());

alert(output);
```

Comment: Do you really need a full fledged constructor here? `M=c=>(s={},r={},{map:(f,e,t)=>s[f+e]=t,mapOutput:(s,o)=>r[s]=o,processEvent:e=>c=s[c+e],getOutput:x=>r[c]})` (score 107) then `var sm = M('Locked');` (without `new`) and all seems to work like a charm

Comment: @edc65 I have edited the code and the snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## OCaml, 217

This is an anonymous function which takes the initial state as its sole parameter and returns a newly constructed object. The function/object are polymorphic in the state, event, and output types.

```
fun i->Hashtbl.(object
val o=create 9
val t=create 9
val mutable s=i
method map a b c=add t(a,b)c
method mapOutput a b=add o a b
method getOutput=try Some(find o s)with _->None
method processEvent e=s<-find t(s,e)end)
```

For a 200+-byte program, there seemed to be remarkably few opportunities for golfing.

Example usage:

```
let k =
fun i->Hashtbl.(object
val o=create 9
val t=create 9
val mutable s=i
method map a b c=add t(a,b)c
method mapOutput a b=add o a b
method getOutput=try Some(find o s)with _->None
method processEvent e=s<-find t(s,e)end)
;;

let pr optint = match optint with
    | Some x -> Printf.printf "%d\n" x
    | None -> Printf.printf "None\n" ;;

let machine = k 0;;

machine#map 0  '0'  1 ;;
machine#map 0  '1'  2 ;;
machine#map 0  '2'  3 ;;
machine#map 1  '3'  0 ;;
machine#map 1  '4'  2 ;;
machine#map 2  '5'  0 ;;
machine#map 2  '6'  1 ;;
machine#map 2  '7'  2 ;;
machine#mapOutput 1 1 ;;
machine#mapOutput 2 10 ;;
machine#mapOutput 3 0 ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '0' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '4' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '7' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '6' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '3' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '1' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '5' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
machine#processEvent '2' ;;
pr machine#getOutput ;;
(* causes exception *)
machine#processEvent '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# (LinqPad) 318 Bytes

#### Golfed Version

```
class S<T,K> where K:Hashtable,new(){public T c;K m=new K(),o=new K();public void Map(T f,char e,T t){if(!m.Contains(f))m.Add(f,new K());((K)m[f]).Add(e,t);}public void MapOutput(int t,object r){o.Add(t,r);}public void ProcessEvent(char e){c=(T)((K)m[c])[e];}public object GetOutput(){return o.Contains(c)?o[c]:null;}}
```

#### Ungolfed Version

```
class S<T,K> where K:Hashtable,new()
{
    public T c;
    K m=new K(),o=new K();
    public void Map(T f,char e,T t){if(!m.Contains(f))m.Add(f,new K());((K)m[f]).Add(e,t);}
    public void MapOutput(int t,object r){o.Add(t,r);}
    public void ProcessEvent(char e){c=(T)((K)m[c])[e];}
    public object GetOutput(){return o.Contains(c)?o[c]:null;}
}
```

#### Initialization:

```
var m = new S<int,Hashtable>();
```

#### Setting initial State:

```
m.c = 0 // or whatever
```

If you don't use it in LinqPad you've got to add another "using System.Collections;" in front (+25 Bytes)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 174 bytes

```
class M
def initialize i
@c=@i=i
@s={}
@o={}
end
def map f,e,t
@s[[f,e]]=t
end
def mapOutput s,o
@o[s]=o
end
def processEvent e
@c=@s[[@c,e]]
end
def getOutput
@o[@c]
end
end
```

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory. This challenge is not challenging in Ruby.